# find n most frequent words in txt file using the terminal but with the cat, "grep ." and tr -d "/r" commands

Tags: text-processing, grep, sort, cat, tr

I would like to find **n** most common words in a text file but with the following conditions:

- `cat` to get the file.
- `grep .` to get the words.
- `tr -d '/r'` to get rid of new lines.

I've managed to get the latter half of the code working with `|sort | uniq -c | sort -nr| head -10`.

Comment: You might want to use the `-o` option for grep: `grep -Eo '[[:alpha:]]+ file'` will print the words one per line.

Answer (score 2):

You mention the use of `grep`, but I don't really see the need for it if the goal is to find the most frequent words. More likely, you just want to split the text file into words, then run your  `| sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -10` pipeline.

The solution that immediately comes to mind (there are without a doubt a number of alternative solutions) is to just use regular expressions via `sed`:

```
sed 's/\s/\n/g'
```

This just states to replace all white space characters (`\s`) with a single newline (`\n`). Coupled together, I would think your solution would look something like so:

```
cat [file] | sed 's/\s/\n/g' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -10 | awk '{print $2}'
```

I added in the final `awk '{print $2}'` to only show the words (not the count), but that's entirely dependent on the purpose of the script.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a homework assignment.

Following all your requirements for `cat`, `grep` and `tr`, matching upper and lower case (HE=He=he=hE), as well as words ending in punctuation marks (he.=he=he,=he!):

```
for word in $(
  cat derp.txt | \
  tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | \
  tr -d '[:punct:]' | \
  tr -d '/r'
)
do
  words[$word]=$(cat derp.txt | grep -c $word)
  echo "${words[$word]} $word" # lots of duplicate output that's filtered out below.
done | sort -u | tail -n 10
```

`grep .` matches everything so is that a typo?

The `tr -d '\r'` is pointless in this context as the input field separator `IFS` for the `for` loop treats both whitespace and newlines as delimiters.

Jason K Lai's solution is probably the best.